# How to frame a MySql query which return result which has all the values in an array?

Tags: mysql

My MySql query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM node as nd
LEFT JOIN term_node as trm_nd ON trm_nd.nid = nd.nid
WHERE nd.title = 'Gadget - definition' 
AND nd.type = 'help_system' 
AND trm_nd.tid IN (434, 456, 25, 293)
```

which returns result like

```
-------------------------------------------------------
nid     title                   type           tid
-------------------------------------------------------
26986   Gadget - definition     help_system     25
26986   Gadget - definition     help_system     293
52421   Gadget - definition     help_system     25
52421   Gadget - definition     help_system     293
73061   Gadget - definition     help_system     25
73061   Gadget - definition     help_system     293
86071   Gadget - definition     help_system     25
86071   Gadget - definition     help_system     293
98596   Gadget - definition     help_system     25
98596   Gadget - definition     help_system     293
98596   Gadget - definition     help_system     434
98596   Gadget - definition     help_system     456
```

But i need result something like below one, which need to return the values that has a nid which is associated with all the array values (434, 456, 25, 293) in tid column

```
-------------------------------------------------------
nid     title                   type           tid
-------------------------------------------------------
98596   Gadget - definition     help_system     25
98596   Gadget - definition     help_system     293
98596   Gadget - definition     help_system     434
98596   Gadget - definition     help_system     456
```

Comment: If you can provide the table structure of `node` and `term_node` tables then that would help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` in your existing query and make it a sub query, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
node n1
JOIN (
  SELECT nid FROM node as nd
  LEFT JOIN term_node as trm_nd ON trm_nd.nid = nd.nid
  WHERE nd.title = 'Gadget - definition' 
  AND nd.type = 'help_system' 
  AND trm_nd.tid IN (434, 456, 25, 293)
  GROUP BY nid
  HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT tid)) = 4
) t1
ON n1.nid = t1.nid
```